# Apply generic to deserialize in Kafka using Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to deserialize the object to process the logic in Flink.
Since the records are consumed via Kafka so I used the `KafkaDeserialization` class.

When the new type of the object is added, I need to add the deserialize class as below.

```
//Existing deserialize class
class ADeserialize {
    extends KafkaDeserializationSchema[TypeAClass] {
  val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper

  override def isEndOfStream(nextElement: TypeAClass): Boolean = false

  override def deserialize(record: ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]): TypeAClass = {
        val jsonNode = mapper.readValue(value, classOf[JsonNode])
    }
  }

  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[TypeAClass] = Types.CASE_CLASS[TypeAClass]
}


//Newly added deserialize class
class BDeserialize {
    extends KafkaDeserializationSchema[TypeBClass] {
  val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper

  override def isEndOfStream(nextElement: TypeBClass): Boolean = false

  override def deserialize(record: ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]): TypeBClass = {
        val jsonNode = mapper.readValue(value, classOf[JsonNode])
    }
  }

  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[TypeBClass] = Types.CASE_CLASS[TypeBClass]
}
```

As you can see, if there are different sources added, then I need to create many times which generates the duplicated sources. To prevent this issue, I think that convering the sources into generic one is idea. But I simply failed to convert it using `KafkaDeserializationSchema`. My flink version is `1.11` since it is legacy.

Any help will be appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What You want is something like :

```
class MyJsonDeserializationSchema[T](implicit typeInfo: TypeInformation[T) extends KafkaDeserializationSchema[T] {
  val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper

  override def isEndOfStream(nextElement: T): Boolean = false

  override def deserialize(record: ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]): T = {
        val jsonNode = mapper.readValue(value, classOf[T])
    }
  }

  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[T] = typeInfo

}
```